# NSubstitute Mock MVC ActionResult Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking, nsubstitute

I want for the Attributes associated to a controller action to be called during the test.

E.g. Code

```
[TestMethod]
    public void UserRegistersWithNonMatchingPasswords()
    {
        var model = GetModel();

        var controller= GetController();
        controller.Register(model); //This is an ActionResult method

        AccountRepository
            .DidNotReceive()
            .IsAccountExists(Arg.Any<string>());

        AccountRepository
            .DidNotReceive()
            .CreateUser(Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<string>());

    }
```

Now the register method looks like

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateModel]
    public ActionResult Register(Model model)
    {
        //The validate model attribute checks the ModelState.IsValid and returns if it's not valid, so any code in the method shouldn't run because of the failed validation.

         IsAccountExists();
         CreateUser();
    }
```

The ValidateModel attribute code (It's from Sitecore Habitat framework)

```
    public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
      var viewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData;

      if (!viewData.ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                               {
                                 ViewData = viewData,
                                 TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
                               };
      }
    }
  }
```

However, it's the MVC framework that calls these attributes, so I wanted to know how to make NSubsitute call it, because it ignores attributes. Thanks.

Comment: Either test the attribute directly or you will need to do an integration test that will allow the framework to invoke the attribute. Show the code for the attribute and the other supporting members in the controller action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test OnActionExecuted filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195405/how-to-test-onactionexecuted-filter)

Comment: @Nkosi I have updated the post with the attribute code. Not sure what you mean by supporting members in the controller action.

Comment: @AshleyMedway I'm not so sure?

Comment: See [How do I unit test a custom ActionFilter in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8508700). That is how you unit test an attribute. If you want it to run before your scenario, that is an integration test that depends on several other pieces of the MVC framework to run. My advice: 1) Unit test your action filter. 2) Make a test to verify that the attribute is on the controller or action. 3) Rely on MVC's unit tests to ensure the rest works.